# Previous Next Link in Wordpress Single Post with Multiple Page Breaks

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Is there a way where I can add a PREVIOUS and NEXT page in the page break numbers?

[image]

I have this single post with multiple page break. Hence, this was automatically generated/created at the bottom of the post for navigation.

What i'm asking is can someone help if its possible to add the "NEXT" and "PREVIOUS" links which contains the url of the next page of the post.

here's a sample link of what I'm working on..

https://myebooklounge.com/del-franco-brothers-adien-book-2-2/

Comment: Never mind, found the answers here! https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75441/changing-wp-link-pages-to-next-page-and-previous-page-buttons

Answer (score 0):

I have this script that can help you

```
Prev 1 2 3 ... 30 31 32 Next
```

Call `pagination('<div class="container">' , '</div>');`

```
 function pagination($before = '', $after = '')
{
    global $wpdb, $wp_query;
    $pagenavi_options = [
        'pages_text' => ('Page %CURRENT_PAGE% of %TOTAL_PAGES%:'),
        'current_text' => '%PAGE_NUMBER%',
        'page_text' => '%PAGE_NUMBER%',
        'first_text' => __('Première page', 'domain'),
        'last_text' => __('Dernière Page', 'domain'),
        'next_text' => __('Suivant &raquo;', 'domain'),
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Précédent', 'domain'),
        'dotright_text' => '...',
        'dotleft_text' => '...',
        'num_pages' => 5, // continuous block of page number,
        'always_show' => 0,
        'num_larger_page_numbers' => 0,
        'larger_page_numbers_multiple' => 5
    ];

    if (! is_single()) {
        $request = $wp_query->request;
        $posts_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
        $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
        $numposts = $wp_query->found_posts;
        $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

        if (empty($paged) || $paged == 0) {
            $paged = 1;
        }

        $pages_to_show = intval($pagenavi_options['num_pages']);
        $larger_page_to_show = intval($pagenavi_options['num_larger_page_numbers']);
        $larger_page_multiple = intval($pagenavi_options['larger_page_numbers_multiple']);
        $pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show - 1;
        $half_page_start = floor($pages_to_show_minus_1 / 2);
        $half_page_end = ceil($pages_to_show_minus_1 / 2);
        $start_page = $paged - $half_page_start;

        if ($start_page <= 0) {
            $start_page = 1;
        }

        $end_page = $paged + $half_page_end;
        if (($end_page - $start_page) != $pages_to_show_minus_1) {
            $end_page = $start_page + $pages_to_show_minus_1;
        }
        if ($end_page > $max_page) {
            $start_page = $max_page - $pages_to_show_minus_1;
            $end_page = $max_page;
        }
        if ($start_page <= 0) {
            $start_page = 1;
        }

        $larger_per_page = $larger_page_to_show * $larger_page_multiple;
        // round_num() custom function - Rounds To The Nearest Value.
        $larger_start_page_start = (round_num($start_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple) - $larger_per_page;
        $larger_start_page_end = round_num($start_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple;
        $larger_end_page_start = round_num($end_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple;
        $larger_end_page_end = round_num($end_page, 10) + ($larger_per_page);

        if ($larger_start_page_end - $larger_page_multiple == $start_page) {
            $larger_start_page_start = $larger_start_page_start - $larger_page_multiple;
            $larger_start_page_end = $larger_start_page_end - $larger_page_multiple;
        }
        if ($larger_start_page_start <= 0) {
            $larger_start_page_start = $larger_page_multiple;
        }
        if ($larger_start_page_end > $max_page) {
            $larger_start_page_end = $max_page;
        }
        if ($larger_end_page_end > $max_page) {
            $larger_end_page_end = $max_page;
        }
        if ($max_page > 1 || intval($pagenavi_options['always_show']) == 1) {
            $pages_text = str_replace("%CURRENT_PAGE%", number_format_i18n($paged), $pagenavi_options['pages_text']);
            $pages_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pages_text);
            echo $before . '<div class="pagenavi">' . "\n";

            if (! empty($pages_text)) {
                // echo '<span class="pages">'.$pages_text.'</span>';
            }

            previous_posts_link($pagenavi_options['prev_text']);

            if ($start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $max_page) {
                $first_page_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pagenavi_options['first_text']);
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link()) . '" class="first" title="' . $first_page_text . '">1</a>';
                if (! empty($pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'])) {
                    echo '<span class="expand">' . $pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'] . '</span>';
                }
            }

            if ($larger_page_to_show > 0 && $larger_start_page_start > 0 && $larger_start_page_end <= $max_page) {
                for ($i = $larger_start_page_start; $i < $larger_start_page_end; $i += $larger_page_multiple) {
                    $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)) . '" class="single_page" title="' . $page_text . '">' . $page_text . '</a>';
                }
            }

            for ($i = $start_page; $i <= $end_page; $i ++) {
                if ($i == $paged) {
                    $current_page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['current_text']);
                    echo '<span class="current">' . $current_page_text . '</span>';
                } else {
                    $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)) . '" class="single_page" title="' . $page_text . '">' . $page_text . '</a>';
                }
            }

            if ($end_page < $max_page) {
                if (! empty($pagenavi_options['dotright_text'])) {
                    echo '<span class="expand">' . $pagenavi_options['dotright_text'] . '</span>';
                }
                $last_page_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pagenavi_options['last_text']);
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($max_page)) . '" class="last" title="' . $last_page_text . '">' . $max_page . '</a>';
            }
            next_posts_link($pagenavi_options['next_text'], $max_page);

            if ($larger_page_to_show > 0 && $larger_end_page_start < $max_page) {
                for ($i = $larger_end_page_start; $i <= $larger_end_page_end; $i += $larger_page_multiple) {
                    $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)) . '" class="single_page" title="' . $page_text . '">' . $page_text . '</a>';
                }
            }
            echo '</div>' . $after . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo $before . '<div class="pagenavi">' . "\n";
        next_post_link('%link');
        previous_post_link('%link');
        echo '</div>' . $after . "\n";
    }
}
```